# How to select color for g.drawLine?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, mixing

I've got an applet with radio buttons to select the color of the line, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

This is what I have thus far. Any suggestions on making color selection work?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ProjectPaint extends Applet {

  private JRadioButton redButton = new JRadioButton("Red");
  private JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
  private JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
  private JRadioButton blackButton = new JRadioButton("Black");
    Graphics g;

  public void init() {
    // Create a border layout design
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // Make a new object of type DrawPanel
     DrawPanel dp = new DrawPanel();
    // Add a draw panel in the center
     add("Center", dp);
    // Add another draw panel for color selection on top
     add("North",new DrawControls(dp));
  }

  int x1;
  int y1;
  class DrawPanel extends Panel
  {
     public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
     {
     // User has started a mouse drag.
     // Remember where:
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;

        return true;
     }

     public boolean mouseDrag(Event e, int x, int y)
     {
     // User is continuing a mouse drag.
     // Draw line from last point to this
     // point:
            g = getGraphics();
        g.drawLine( x1,y1, x,y );

     // Remember new "last point":
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;

        return true;
     }
  }
  class DrawControls extends Panel
  {
     public DrawControls(DrawPanel target)
     {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioButtonGroup.add(redButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(blueButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(greenButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(blackButton);
        panel.add(redButton);
        panel.add(blueButton);
        panel.add(greenButton);
        panel.add(blackButton);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        redButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        blueButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        greenButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        blackButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
            blackButton.doClick();
     }
  }
  private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
            int color = -1;
        if(e.getSource() == redButton)
        {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == blueButton)
        {
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == greenButton)
        {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == blackButton)
        {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `Graphics` instance, `g`, is null when you call `setColor` on it.

Comment: You should be extending `JApplet`, not Applet since you are creating a Swing applet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Graphics` reference has not been assigned hence the `NPE`.

Don't attempt any custom painting from an `ActionListener` or `MouseListener`. Instead use a `Color` class member variable to set the color. For Swing applications, all custom painting should be done in the `paintComponent` method. In this case `DrawPanel` will need to changed so as to extend `JPanel` so that it can override the method. Add the `@Override` annotation and make sure to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.

`JApplet` has support for the JFC/Swing component architecture so use that also.

Comment: so I have a variable set up below `Graphics g;` as the very top called `int color = 0;. I changed my actionperformed to update the int with a number, and I made a paintComponent method that sets the color according to the `int` value of `color`. I get no error, but the color doesn't change when I select a radio button.

Comment: `java.awt.Panel` does not extend `JComponent` - add an `@Override  ` annotation and see for yourself. Don't use a `Graphics` object as a class member variable - use the one in `paintComponent`. Instead use a `Color` reference rather than `int`. Also see my updates

Comment: I'm so terrible at this, dunno why I went into computer science ha. I'll look over the answer and try to figure it out. Changing it to JPanel made my DrawPanel not come up at all, but I figured you probably expected that. As for using a color reference, I'm not sure how I would do that

Comment: Your `drawLine` statements go in the `paintComponent` method

Comment: So with the code above, I need to 1) Write a `paintComponent` method 2) Move `Graphics g;` down to my `paintComponent` method. 3) Move all painting methods from `ActionListener` and `MouseListener` to the `paintComponent` 4) Change `extends Panel` to `extends JPanel` and put in `@Override` inside the `DrawPanel` method. 5) Invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`... inside the `paintComponent` method?.. Is that everything I need to fix?

Comment: `paintComponent` already has a Graphics object so just use that. BTW I don't see any `addMouseListener` method call for `DrawPanel`...